# Self-relationship (Issue) (parent_category_id, multiple_values error)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table (Category):

```
id - category id
parent_category_id - (which obviously relates back to id) -
name - category name
```

In the model (Category):

```
class Category extends ExtendedModel
{
protected $table = 'categories';

function rel_parent_categories() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_category_id');
}
}
```

and in the Category (frozennode)

```
'edit_fields' => array(
'name',
'parent_category_id' => array(
'title' => 'Parent Category',
'relationship' => 'rel_parent_categories',
'select' => '(:table).name',

),
'active' => array(
'title' => 'Active',
'type' => 'bool',
),
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is for the user to be capable of 1. getting the parent category name, and 2. get all categories with no parent id (which means they are parent categories) listed too.

This is the first step; but I'm getting the error: multiple_values.

Error:
An invalid option 'multiple_values' was searched for in the 'parent_category_id'

Answer (score 0):

Try defining both relationship directions like so:

```
class Category extends ExtendedModel
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function rel_parent_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_category_id');
    }

    public function rel_children_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_category_id');
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, what does `ExtendedModel` do?

Comment: "An invalid option 'multiple_values' was searched for in the 'parent_category_id' field"

Comment: all it does is to restrict some columns when I want too, but doesn't for that one.